# setInterval for each of an array of elements

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've got a set of DOM elements, each of which needs its own timer. Eventually I'll be checking every X milliseconds to see whether a particular child of that element is present or not, but for right now it doesn't much matter what happens inside the timer.

The catch is that I want the timers to *stop* eventually. I can set up the timers with setInterval just fine, they work fine, but I can't figure out how to get clearInterval to end them.

I could probably do this with one big timer that watches every relevant element, but now I'm curious and want to figure this out. I figure I'm probably doing something wrong in the way I declare or start the timers, or clearInterval is targeting the setInterval functions incorrectly.

Here's my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let interval = 1000;
  let base_count = 1;
  let current_counts = [];
  let timers = [];

  // Count up from base to max and update the text to match.
  function counter(p, maxCount, i) {
    p.text(p.text().slice(0,5) + ': ' + current_counts[i]);
    if (current_counts[i] > maxCount) {
      clearInterval(timers[i]);
    }
    current_counts[i]++;
  }

  // Counters for each thing start at 1
  current_counts = Array($('.thing').length).fill(base_count);
  // Each thing gets its own timer.
  timers = $('.thing').map(function (i, e) {
    function start() {
      return setInterval(
        counter,
        interval,
        $(e),
        10, // Max value for counter
        i // Which paragraph are we on?
      );
    }
    return start;
  });

  // Start the timers.
  timers.each((i, e) => e());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test1 thing">Test1</p>
<p class="test2 thing">Test2</p>
<p class="test3 thing">Test3</p>
```

Comment: *' I'll be checking every X milliseconds to see whether a particular child of that element is present or not...'* you might want to look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @pilchard Oh sweet, the last thing I heard about that did that looked like it was never going to happen. (Maybe that was Mutation Events? It was years ago.) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't storing the intervals anywhere.

If you change the following:

```
timers.each((i, e) => e());
```

to:

```
timers = timers.map((i, e) => e());
```

it'll work.

Comment: Yes! I guess I was just running the intervals and not actually keeping a reference to them. Thank you for the help.

Comment: my answer was the same and I  post it before you but OP still marked this as answer :)

Comment: using this solution, how would i then restart a specified interval from the map?

Comment: @gorillagoat You need to create a new variable. So rather than doing timers = timers.map((i, e) => e()); you use something like let timersID = timers.map((i, e) => e()); That way, you still have references to timers.

Answer (score 1):

As @pilchard said, [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) should fit your use case. Though this does not answer your question so here its the answer:

On the browser `setInterval` returns an id for the interval created, so you can use it on `clearInterval` as below:

```js
// create the interval
let intervalId = setInterval(callback, time);

// clear the interval using the id
clearInverval(intervalId);
```

Comment: That'll work for one interval - what about for several of them, where I don't know how many there will be beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

`e()` returns all timers, then simple clear them out later

```js
var tmrs = timers.map((i, e) => e());

// stop all timers 
tmrs.forEach(x=> clearInverval(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutation observer is widely although not universally supported, and that is what I would use here as well.  But your code could also work and would be more widely supported.  You declare the array current_counts, but then you never assign any values to it, so current_counts[i] will always be undefined, and your check will always fail.

```js
if (current_counts[i] > maxCount) {
      clearInterval(timers[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Look under the line that says   // Counters for each thing start at 1.